# How to get Stripe payment transaction details in JAVA (Stripe Android SDK) after payment completed

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using `com.stripe:stripe-android:20.0.0` SDK for the android stripe payment process. I did all the code and payment get success and fire on payment success event. But I did not find any way to get my succeeded payment Transaction ID or any Transaction details like other payment gateways. Even the `paymentSheetResult` object has no other details attributes.

```
 private void onPaymentSheetResult(
        final PaymentSheetResult paymentSheetResult
) {
    if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Completed) {

        PaymentSheetResult pr = paymentSheetResult;
        showToast("Payment complete!");
    } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Canceled) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Payment canceled!");
    } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Failed) {
        Throwable error = ((PaymentSheetResult.Failed) paymentSheetResult).getError();
        showAlert("Payment failed", error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the PaymentIntent ID from the `PaymentsheetResult`.

But you can derive the PaymentIntent ID from the `clientSecret` that you pass to initialize the PaymentSheet. The format of `clientSecret` is `pi_ABC_secret_123`, and anything before the `_secret` is the PayementIntent ID (e.g., `pi_ABC`).

Comment: Hi can you please provide a working example, i am having the same problem.

<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309259/stripe-android-sdk-paymentresult-is-not-providing-transaction-details>